# Failing to display images in pygame using blit

Tags: python, pygame

I have the following code where i try to load two images using .blit:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 1600
height = 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

attackImg = pygame.image.load('attack.png')
healImg = pygame.image.load('heal.png')
manaImg = pygame.image.load('mana.png')
moveImg = pygame.image.load('move.png')
shieldImg = pygame.image.load('shield.png')
stunImg = pygame.image.load('stun.png')


while True:
  screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
  screen.blit(healImg, (100, 800))
  screen.blit(attackImg, (200, 800))
  pygame.display.update()
```

I get no error messages when running the code, but the images don´t show up. The image files are available and their right names have been used. I have read several tutorials and don´t see what I´ve done wrong. The code is written and ran in repl.it if that makes any difference. Please help me understand why the images are not showing up and what needs to be changed.

Comment: It looks OK.  Maybe try it on a local python installation.

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted your code and firstly, the window didn't show up. Your code didn't have the 'event loop' in it. You pretty much always have to do it, else the window won't launch. You also might usually want to make a `running = True` variable. Without that your program is not likely to close normally.
Heres the correct code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 1600
height = 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

attackImg = pygame.image.load('attack.png')
healImg = pygame.image.load('heal.png')

running = True
while running:
  screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
  for event in pygame.event.get(): # <--- 'event loop'
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
  screen.blit(healImg, (100, 800))
  screen.blit(attackImg, (200, 800))
  pygame.display.update()
```

If that does not work it probably is just that the images cover each other or they are being 'blitted' outside the view. In that case, write a comment.